# Is it possible to returns other fields when you aggregate results on Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-aggregation

Here is the mappings of my index PublicationsLikes:

- id : String
- account : String
- api : String
- date : Date

I'm currently making an aggregation on ES where I group the results counts by the id (of the publication).

```
{
    "key": "<publicationId-1>",
    "doc_count": 25
},
{
    "key": "<publicationId-2>",
    "doc_count": 387
},
{
    "key": "<publicationId-3>",
    "doc_count": 7831
}
```

The returned "key" (the id) is an information but I also need to select another fields of the publication like account and api. A bit like that:

```
{
   "key": "<publicationId-1>",
   "api": "Facebook",
   "accountId": "65465z4fe6ezf456ezdf",
   "doc_count": 25
},
{
  "key": "<publicationId-2>",
  "api": "Twitter",
  "accountId": "afaez5f4eaz",
  "doc_count": 387
}
```

How can I manage this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement is best achieved by `top_hits` aggregation, where you can sort the documents in each bucket and choose the first and also you can control which fields you want returned:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "publications": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": ["api","accountId"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subaggregation for this.

```
GET /PublicationsLikes/_search
{
 "aggs" : {
  "ids": {
   "terms": {
    "field": "id"
   },
   "aggs": {
    "accounts": {
     "terms": {
      "field": "account",
      "size": 1
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Your result will not exactly what you want but it will be a bit similar:

```
{
    "key": "<publicationId-1>",
    "doc_count": 25,
    "accounts": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "<account-1>",
          "doc_count": 25
        }
      ]
    }
},
{
    "key": "<publicationId-2>",
    "doc_count": 387,
    "accounts": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "<account-2>",
          "doc_count": 387
        }
      ]
    }
},
{
    "key": "<publicationId-3>",
    "doc_count": 7831,
    "accounts": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "<account-3>",
          "doc_count": 7831
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

You can also check [the link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations) to find more information

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for your quick replies. I think the first solution is the most "beautiful" (in terms of request but also to retrieves the results) but both seems to be sub aggregations queries.

`{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "publications": {
         "terms": {
            "size": 0,
            "field": "publicationId"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "sample": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": ["accountId", "api"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`

I think I must be careful to size=0 parameter, so, because I work in the Java Api, I decided to put INT.Max instead of 0.

Thnaks a lot guys.